# Neural Network is producing different result in R

Tags: r, deep-learning, neural-network, random-seed

I am running a feed-forward neural network in R using the `library(Keras)` and `library(reticulate)`. Every time I run my model, it produces different results.

I used `set.seed()` function in R to be able to reproduce the same results for the models. However, since the neural network models are originally fitted in python environment (not in R) it is producing different results. Is there any function to set the seed in python for it? I have my piece of code in the following.

```r
    library(caret)
    library(dplyr)
    library(keras)
    library(reticulate)
    virtualenv_create("r-reticulate", python = install_python())
    set.seed(1234)
    reticulate::install_miniconda()  
    install_keras(envname = "r-reticulate")


    #Single layer feedforward NN
    NN_classic <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
      layer_dense(units = 10000 , activation = "relu" ,
                  input_shape = ncol(x_train) ) %>%
      layer_dropout(rate = 0.1) %>%
      layer_dense(units = 2 , activation = "softmax")

    NN_classic %>% compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy",
                      optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(), metrics = c("accuracy"))

    #fitting the model
    system.time(
      history <- NN_classic %>% fit(
        x_train,y_train , epochs = 50, batch_size=4096,
        validation_data = list(x_test,y_test)
        )
    )

    #prediction on test set
    prob.NN<- predict(NN_classic,x_test, type = "prob")
    pred.NN <- ifelse(prob.NN[,1] > 0.5 , 0, 1)
    table(pred.NN, y_test[,2])  #confusion matrix
    #error rate
    1-mean(pred.NN==y_test[,2])  
    #roc curve
    test_roc = roc(test_data$NB_Claim~prob.NN[,1])
    as.numeric(test_roc$auc)
```